# What is the derivative of $\int_{x^3}^{x^2} e^{y^2} dy$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

My only idea is to calculate this integral but I know it is very hard to calculate it so there must be some smarter way. I will appreciate any hint or help.

Comment: This is a classic fundamental theorem of calculus problem. Go over that section in your favorite resource and feel free to edit your post with any difficulties that arise after that.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried to calculate this integral but i couldn't do this.

Comment: You won't be able to do so because $e^{y^2}$ has no primitive expressible with elementary functions. But if $F$ is a primitive of $y\mapsto e^{y^2}$, then your function is $F(x^2)-F(x^3)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consequence of the **first fundamental theorem of calculus** is that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t) \ dt = f(x)$$

To do this problem, you can split the integral into two parts:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{x^3}^{x^2}e^{y^2} \ dy &= \int_{x^3}^{0}e^{y^2} \ dy + \int_{0}^{x^2}e^{y^2} \ dy \\
&= -\int_{0}^{x^3}e^{y^2} \ dy + \int_{0}^{x^2}e^{y^2} \ dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{x^2}e^{y^2} \ dy -\int_{0}^{x^3}e^{y^2} \ dy 
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Then you'll need to substitute for the upper limits and use the chain rule when you differentiate.

Answer (score 3):

There's no nice formula for $\int e^{y^2} \; dy$, so you can't solve this directly. This is intentional to get you to use the fundamental theorem of calculus. I'd suggest just calling the antiderivative $F(y)$.

- If $F(y)$ is the antiderivative of $e^{y^2}$, what is $\int_{x^3}^{x^2} e^{y^2} \; dy$? (in terms of $F$)
- Take the derivative of your answer above with respect to $x$
- Use the fact that you know what $F'(x)$ is to write your answer in closed form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ninad Munshi, Tuvasbien, Kman3, TomKern for responding to my question.

So derevative of this function is $2x \cdot e^{x^4}-3x^2 \cdot e^{x^6}$ ?